# How to upgrade Google Android Market Application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

The new Android in-app billing (http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) page says: "To test in-app billing in an application you must install the application on an Android-powered device. You cannot use the Android emulator to test in-app billing. The device you use for testing must run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or later platform (API level 4 or higher), and have the most current version of the Android Market application installed. If a device is not running the most current Android Market application, your application won't be able to send in-app billing requests to Android Market."

and "A device must be running version 2.3.0 (or higher) of the Android Market application to support in-app billing."

I have a Galaxy Tablet running 2.2.11 version of the Market app that I'm trying to use for developing my application. Can some body please let me know or give me any pointers on how can I upgrade it to 2.3.0 or higher ? Does it also require a latest version (gingerbread) of Android too on my device?

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_about.html

I believe we are still in the "early development" phase which: "Provides an early look at documentation and sample application" and that's it...
So... waiting is the answer for now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The market application updates itself. I don't believe 2.3.0 has been rolled out yet which is why you're not seeing it ([This message](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/3189b6750a4a0f6c) shows it hadn't been rolled out on the 3rd and I've seen no changes in the status since then).

Comment: Ahh! thank you - any pointers/insight on how to test the new in-app billing?