# How to upgrade the Market Application from version 1.82?

Tags: android, google-play, cyanogenmod

The README for the market billing sample states:

> In-app billing requires version 2.3.0 of the Android Market
>   application. To run the sample application you must have this version
>   (or a newer version) installed on your device. You can check the
>   version of the Android Market application by doing the following:
>
> 1. Open Settings on your device and touch Applications.
> 2. In Application Settings, touch Manage applications.
> 3. Touch All to list all applications.
> 4. Scroll down and touch the Market application.
> 5. The version number appears under Market at the top of the screen.

Well, I did just that and discovered that my Market version is very old: **1.82**

I thought it would update itself automatically (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000823/how-to-upgrade-google-android-market-application)), but for some strange reason it never did, and I can't find a way to do this manually.

I suspect this has to do with the fact that My Android 2.2.1 is a `CyanogenMod-6.1.0-N1`.

Any idea how to update the Market application in my phone?

**Update:** I just discovered [this thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/15347-solved-force-close-with-new-market-re-sign-the-apk/), which allows me to report success in upgrading to version [2.2.7](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/15281-how-to-update-market-to-2x/page__view__findpost__p__133958). Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the Vending-2.2.7-signed-testkeys.update.zip file
2. Copied the Vending.apk inside it to the sdcard
3. Downloaded **ZipSigner 2** (from the Market)
4. Selected the new Vending.apk as input, and specified signed-vending.apk as output.
5. Selected "platform" as key/mode
6. Signed the file (success).
7. Ran the resulting signed-vending.apk from File Manager.

Wow! That is some progress. I believe the way from here to 2.3.0 would be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been able to upgrade to the latest 3.4.4, thanks to the [first reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_market#References) in Wikipedia. Here is what I did:

```
1. Downloaded the "Android Market 3.4.4 With Noticeable Speed Improvements" file.
2. Copied the downloaded AndroidMarket_v3.4.4.apk to the sdcard
3. Downloaded ZipSigner 2 (from the Market)
4. Selected the new Vending.apk as input, and specified signed-v3.4.4.apk as output.
5. Selected "platform" as key/mode
6. Signed the file (success).
7. Checked "Allow installation of non-Market applications".
8. Ran the resulting signed-v3.4.4.apk via File Manager.
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

One more solution could be, go to menu, select "update over wifi only". Whenever you come under wifi range, if there are any updates, it will give you a notification. With this you can always have the latest version of the market app since even market app is an apk file :)

Comment: I tried that first. It didn't work for me. I believe this only works for devices in which the Market app is *not* part of the ROM... Apps which aren't part of the system of course get updated via this method.